# Given a gradle project that uses gradlew, how can I tell what version of gradle said project is using?

Tags: gradle

For example, given the [sonarqube](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube) source code, which uses `gradlew`, how can I check what is the version of gradle that this project is using?

I assume it must be using an exact version because if not, there would be no point in using `gradlew`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. from the gradle project you want to check, you can execute following command:

   ```
   $ ./gradlew --version

   Gradle 4.5.1
   ...
   ```
2. you can check version in the *distributionUrl* from wrapper configuration file *./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties* , example with sonarqube: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

   ```
   #Mon Apr 16 10:55:26 PDT 2018
   distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   distributionPath=wrapper/dists
   zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5.1-bin.zip
   ```
3. you can add following line in build script to pring the currently used Gradle version when executing the build, thanks to the [Gradle API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html)

   ```
   println "Gradle version is: " + gradle.gradleVersion
   ```

Comment: the way 3. is very interesting. It opens up various possibilities. I didn't know that existed. thank you!